# Inserting Queries into a RDBMS from a Java Application

Tags: java, database

If we would like to insert 10,000 rows of data into a RDBMS from our Java application, I assume a simple way to do so would be to use a while loop.... however surley this is infact rather sending 10,000 inserts of one row as opposed to one insert of 10,000 rows.

I guess I am looking for a way to generate the one insert without having to manually write out 10,000 lines of code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical case where you want to use prepared statement. Sending the SQL once parametericed to the RDMS and than filling batches with data…

Answer (score 0):

Turn auto-commit off in the JDBC connection, and call commit on a regular basis.

Comment: Awsome so somthing like 
while(i != 10000)
{
ISNERT INTO ....
}
commit(); // Im assuming this is wrong but would this be the kind of way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports transactions, you can do it in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is to *generate* the inserts then you could use a scripting language to generate the inserts using data from a text file. I had use groovy to do that and it was very simple.
If you want to know the most eficient way to *execute* the inserts you probably want to use jdbc executeBatch for that. [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/BatchUpdateInsert.htm)